# Doubt about developing the summation $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1) \cdot 3^{2n-2}(1-\varepsilon )^{2n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, cellular-automata

In the book "Contours, Convex Sets and Cellular Automata" (Andrei Toom), I've found the following:

> [...] the probability that there is no percolation does not exceed
>
> $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1) \cdot  3^{2n-2}(1-\varepsilon )^{2n}$
>
> For (1 - ε) small enough this sum is less than one and this is what we need. In fact, this sum equals
>
> $\left ( \frac{x}{3(1-x)} \right )^2$ where $x = \left ( 3(1-\varepsilon ) \right )^2$.

I did not understand how he derived the summation to the other expression. Can someone give me a help?

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\big(3(1-\epsilon)\big)^2$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 2}(n-1)3^{2n-2}(1-\epsilon)^{2n}&=\sum_{n\ge 2}(n-1)\big(3(1-\epsilon)\big)^{2(n-1)}(1-\epsilon)^2\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 2}(n-1)x^{n-1}(1-\epsilon)^2\\
&=\frac19\sum_{n\ge 2}(n-1)x^n\\
&=\frac{x^2}9\sum_{n\ge 2}(n-1)x^{n-2}\\
&=\frac{x^2}9\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{x^2}9\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\right)\\
&=\frac{x^2}9\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)\\
&=\frac{x^2}9\cdot\frac1{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{3(1-x)}\right)^2\,.
\end{align*}$$